# UIImage not loading on view did load in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiimage

When I am loading my application button image is not loading on first view on `viewDidLoad`, but it loads after `viewWillAppear`.

Here is my code,

```
if (activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    CGRect frameloginscreenbutton1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768,1004);
    [loginscreenbutton1 setFrame:frameloginscreenbutton1];

}
else if(activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{       
    CGRect frameloginscreenbutton1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
    [loginscreenbutton1 setFrame:frameloginscreenbutton1];
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: what is code of your button ?

Comment: if (activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
 {
  CGRect frameloginscreenbutton1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768,1004);
  [loginscreenbutton1 setFrame:frameloginscreenbutton1];

 }
 else if(activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || activityorientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
 {  
  CGRect frameloginscreenbutton1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
  [loginscreenbutton1 setFrame:frameloginscreenbutton1];
 }

Comment: @user968597 Please add the code in the question by editing it.

Comment: Actually when application is running iPad 1, it shows button image. But when application is runs on iPad 2, it does not showing button image

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends on whether the button is being loaded from a nib or not. If it is being loaded from a nib, then it does not exist at the time `viewDidLoad` is called. You can verify this yourself with a breakpoint. By the time `viewDidAppear:` is called it has been created.

If you want to configure items that are loaded from Interface Builder (whether from a xib file or a Storyboard) then the correct time to do so is by overriding `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 0):

I think because is not created yes or something like this...

you can use this method to setframe in viewdidload after a zero delay.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(setButtonFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

-(void) setButtonFrame 
{
   //your code
}
```

if it doesnt work try other delays forexmple 0.1